# Sparse-cut approximation for well connected graphs

Tags: approximation-algorithms, spectral-graph-theory, max-flow-min-cut, unique-games-conjecture, promise-problems

*[Theorem](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=69876)*: For any graph $G=(V,E)$, there is a polynomial time algorithm that finds a cut $S \subseteq V$ with conductance at most  $\sqrt{2\big(1 − \lambda(G)\big)}$.

If I understand [UGC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_games_conjecture) correctly, the above result is tight for general graph under UGC.

*Question*: Can we obtain a better approximation if we have the promise - $mincut(G) = O(\log n )$?

Comment: what is $\lambda$? what is conductance?

Comment: @Saeed: The 2nd largest value of the normalized Adjaceny matrix.